# Cannot find file “/etc/my.cnf” in MySQL 5.6 (mysql-5.6.26-win32)

Tags: mysql

I have read [this article](http://ozview-web.blogspot.in/2009/04/how-to-increase-maxallowedpacket-size.html) but I can not find `/etc/my.cnf` file/folder. I have `mysql-5.6.26-win32`. Which version of MySQL I have to download for editing this file?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Windows, look in `%PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6`.  It may also be called my.ini.

If you don't see it in there, reference the table of locations on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html

Answer (score 0):

The `my.cnf` isn’t always in the same location on different systems. And MySQL also might load a few different `my.cnf` files when it starts up.

So the best way to determine which `my.cnf` is being used is to run this command from the command line:

```
mysql --help
```

Now that will basically spit out a wall of text of MySQL configuration options, but look for a chunk of text near the middle that reads something like this; taken from an Ubuntu 12.04.5 server but the concept is the same:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

The paths `/etc/my.cnf`, `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, `/usr/etc/my.cnf` and `~/.my.cnf` show the order in which different MySQL config files are loaded.

Now check each location to see which one is the main `my.cnf` your setup uses and just edit and adjust that file as you see fit. Save it, restart MySQL and the edits and adjustments should be in place.

#### Addendum for Linux/Unix users who need to figure out where their `my.cnf` files are.

And while it seems you are on a Windows system, if you are on a Linux/Unix system you can pipe that output through `grep` to make your life easier like this:

```
mysql --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
```

The results should be just this:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Which is of course easier to find/understand than going through a wall of MySQL configuration options.